# Can you Hide files in c?

Tags: c

Does anybody know if it is possible to hide files or make them invisible to other users? Or, does creating file in "w" mode achieve invisibility?

Ex:
If I create a file like this:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("aFile","w");
```

Can other users on my system read it?

I guess I'm asking for the C way to add access modifiers to files in C, sort of like the chmod command does..

Comment: If you are looking for `chmod` here is the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/chmod) of the C function

Comment: `chmod` does not provide "invisibility".. however you have a chmod system call in C

Comment: to make a file invisible you have can add "." before the file's name.
For eg : a file named ".file" is not visible. Thus you can change your file name from "aFile" to ".aFile"

Comment: @ Could you please provide some documentation on the .afile invisibility you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set access permission when using `fopen`.
Use `CreateFile` instead to open file and set access permissions.

Comment: Also it is possible to use `SetFileAttributes()` to change attributes of created file (if we are talking about Windows).

Comment: File attribute and file access is two different thing. Hidden attribute achieves invisibility, but not protection against others writing. chmod on the other hand limits access permissions, which is the same CreateFile can do.